# Avoid, combine duplicated data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm very new to MySQL and database design. This is my data base below. It works okay, but there is a problem with it. If I add and "Order" to "Invoice" there might be 2 orders with the same ProductCode. How do I handle this, is there anyway I can just add their quantity together if this situation happens? Thank you
[image]

Comment: What's the problem with that situation?  Why would it be bad if there are multiple orders with the same product?  That's a pretty standard occurrence in this sort of model.

Comment: @dg99 For example: if you order product "a1" with a quantity of 2, then you order "a1" again with quantity of 5 this time. Shouldn't a good decide be able to tell that and combine it into 1 order of "a1" with quantity of 7 ?